# Pasar valor a través de un evento en tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

tengo un programa hecho en tkinter, donde al iniciar tengo una ventana con 2 botones, cada botón me llama a una clase que dicha clase, tiene varios widgets, uno de esos widgets es un entry. Y quiero que al darle al ENTER en el entry, me ejecute un función.

Me imprime esto

```
<KeyPress event state=Mod2 keysym=Return keycode=36 char='\r' x=127 y=21>
```

La función a que llamó es:

```
def buscar_Modulos(self, txt_Buscar=None):
        try:
            valor_aBuscar = txt_Buscar
            print(valor_aBuscar)
        except:
            mb.showerror("ERROR","Esta vacio o no existe el modulo.\nPrueba a buscar por CLAVE o el MODULO completo")
```

La llamada a esa función la realizó así:

```
self.DESVfr1_entModulo.bind("<Return>", self.buscar_Modulos)
```

Pero no funciona.

Si embargo si lo hago desde un button, si funciona:

```
self.DESVfr1_btnBuscar = ttk.Button(self.DESV_frame1,
                                                    text='Buscar',
                                                    image=self.BuscarModulo_icon,
                                                    state='disabled',
                                                    command=lambda: self.buscar_Modulos(self.DESVfr1_entModulo.get()),
                                                    style='DESV.TButton'
                                                    )
```

Y me imprime el texto que ingreso en el entry, y ya puedo trabajar con ese texto, pero no sé porque al darle a ENTER no me funciona.
Y si en el evento , pongo el mismo código que el del button, me refiero a esto :

```
lambda: self.buscar_Modulos(self.DESVfr1_entModulo.get())
```

Me sale este error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/_init_.py", line 1705, in _call_
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ese error es muy común y se debe a que las funciones que contienen argumentos, el parámetro `command` pasa todos esos argumentos en la devolución de la llamada en el caso de un control como un botón, cuando usted usa una función anónima `lambda`, es una función que no toma todos los argumentos de una función, el error que está obteniendo está implicando que lo que sea que lo llame le deba pasar el argumento necesario, a veces las devoluciones de llamada pasan un objeto de evento y a veces como en este caso lo ignora, por lo que generalmente la solución es esto si la devolución de la llamada en un `Entry`:

```
lambda x: self.buscar_Modulos(self.DESVfr1_entModulo.get())
```

O también:

```
lambda x=None: self.buscar_Modulos(self.DESVfr1_entModulo.get())
```

> La `x` en esto caso es una constante que representa un argumento no utilizado para la devolución de la llamada

> Nota: Tenga en cuenta que `command` hace referencia a la función o
> método que se llamará cuando se haga clic en el botón, `command` en
> otros controles es un argumento u otro mpetodo, por lo cual `command` en este caso llama la
> función de una manera directa cuando usa varias funciones o funciones
> anónimas `lambda`.

Comment: Gracias lo tendré en cuenta.. muchas gracias

Comment: una cosa, mi función está así:.                                             def buscar_Modulos(self, txt_Buscar=None), la dejó así o debo cambiar el txt_Buscar=None, a solo la palabra txt_Buscar o event??

Comment: Dejaría `txt_Buscar=None` al ser un argumento adicional y al usarse como una variable dentro de la llamada de la función en `valor_aBuscar = txt_Buscar` y si es necesario en parte de la ejecución del resto del código, por tanto usar `event` o `event=None` sería para algún tipo de método `bind()` en la llamada a una función.

Comment: Ok Gracias John entiendo 